# How to make md-list in md-tab-body horizontally scrollable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am embedding a list of items into a tab-body. Since the list is too long for the screen I need to scroll to the end of the list. When I set layout="column" I got a vertical list and a scroll bar automatically shows up. But when I set layout="row" (like in the code below), there is no scroll bar for my horizontal list and I cannot scroll horizontally. So I cannot get to the end of the list. Is this a bug or am I missing anything? Note: When I have my horizontal list without embedded in a tab-body the scrolling works just fine.

Anybody an idea?

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height  md-stretch-tabs>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label class="tab-label">
            tab label
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body >
                <md-list layout="row">
                  <md-list-item ng-repeat="listitem in listitems"></md-list-item>
                </md-list>
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
```

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular2 ?

Comment: angularJS and angular material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. If anybody is interested:

- remove dynamic-height directive
- specify the following css:

  .tabs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
    }

  .full-size {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  }

  - apply css in html code: apply in outer div class "tabs-wrapper", apply in md-tabs class "full-size"

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues where md-dynamic-height doesn't account for the scroll bar. Try specifying a sufficient height and see if your scroll bar appears.

Comment: I don't see a solution in specifying a height. I need a horizontal scroll bar so I don't need a vertical limit, right? However, specifying a width also doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a vertical limit as much as I am saying that when the height is calculated, the scrollbar is not accounted for. I'm not certain, but I think if you define the height to be taller than the default rendering, then there will be room for display of the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom. I've encountered this issue before and that solved it for me.